# What are the criteria for the Beta badge?

Tags: support, badges

The [Beta](https://literature.stackexchange.com/help/badges/30/beta) badge is supposed to be awarded when you:

> Voted 10 times, added 3 posts score > 0, and visited the site on 3 separate days during the private beta.

But there are plenty of us who've voted a lot more than 10 times, contributed a lot more than 3 positively-scored posts, and visited the site on all 4 days of private beta so far. Yet nobody has been awarded this badge. Why not?

**What are the 'unspoken' criteria for the Beta badge?**

Comment: Do meta posts count for the badge?

Comment: @Gallifreyan No.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Beta badge is not awarded before the site enters public beta. Let's look at the newest site to enter public beta [Internet of Things](https://iot.stackexchange.com/). [Private beta](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/94224/internet-of-things) started on December 12th, and public beta started on January 3rd - which was when all [19 people to get the Beta badge](https://iot.stackexchange.com/help/badges/30/beta) were awarded it.

So, we all have a couple more weeks to go before we can get it -  assuming, of course, Literature Stack Exchange makes it to public beta, which we can't take for granted. I can tell you from experience that getting the badge makes you feel like you've done your part, and there's less motivation to keep contributing - not what you want to happen during the private beta. Thus, the badge isn't awarded until we've all gotten through the critical period.

Comment: Also a good possibility to incentivize the people after the flurry. [This](http://meta.iot.stackexchange.com/q/145/78) got a few more posts on IoT :)